# upgrade your database to Oracle Database 12c ERROR

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have upgrade my database to Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1) and then plug it into a CDB, the automatic SQL Tuning Advisor generates the following error:

```
ORA-65040: operation not allowed from within a pluggable database
```

what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the PDB where you see the ORA-65040 error for the automatic SQL Tuning Advisor, use the DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_PROGRAM('AUTO_SQL_TUNING_PROG') procedure to delete the existing old AUTO_SQL_TUNING_PROG program, and then run the execsqlt.sql script to re-create it. You can find the script in the ORACLE_HOME/admin directory.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Orcale docs **3.24.1.4 Bug 16654392**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/READM/chapter12101.htm#READM381):

> **Workaround:**  Connect to the PDB where you see the ORA-65040 error for
>   the automatic SQL Tuning Advisor, use the
>   DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_PROGRAM('AUTO_SQL_TUNING_PROG') procedure to
>   delete the existing old AUTO_SQL_TUNING_PROG program, and then run the
>   execsqlt.sql script to re-create it. You can find the script in the
>   ORACLE_HOME/admin directory.
>
> Automatic SQL Tuning Advisor can be configured at the CDB level only.
>
> You can configure the following automated maintenance tasks at the CDB
>   or PDB level:
>
> - Optimizer Statistics gathering
> - Segment Advisor